# How to get the exact sale amount in Salesforce ios

Tags: ios, salesforce

Is there a field that returns the exact sale amount in salesforce?. Currently, i'm using the "Amount" from "Opportunity". I want to get the exact Amount (ex. 1,234.00) not the estimated amount.

Comment: If there's no answer, why its down voted?.

Answer (score 0):

Can't Find a field so i just formatted the result from Amount:

```
-(NSString *) convertAmount:(NSNumber *) number{
if ([number isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    number = 0;
}
unsigned long long value = [number longLongValue];

NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // to get commas (or locale equivalent)

NSString *result = [fmt stringFromNumber:@(value)];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@".00"];

return result;
}
```

And to use it:

```
NSString * TestingVal = [self convertAmount:VALUE_FETCHED];
NSLog(@"Amount Value: %@", TestingVal);
```